# how to create clickable hyperlink in textview by retrieving url link from firebase

Tags: android, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database, hyperlink, textview

so, i have created child 'User' in my realtime db, in 'User' there's children 'link' that contains string of the url link (link inputed optional by user). the problem is i want to retrieve the 'link' with value string into my hyperlink textView that when it's clicked it will go into the link address. turns out i'm just getting the url string in my textview but the link is not clickable.

i already search some tutorial, but mostly it shows to me to open link into webview or some search that i get is dynamic link which is i don't think i need it if there's another way to create a clickable hyperlink in textview. how can i solve this? what should i use? and how do i make the textview is clickable and open the link outside the app.

here's the database

[image]

here's the result when i try to get the link (it should be a link that can be clicked, not just a textview)

[image]

here's the function for getting the user info in fragment.

```
private fun userInfo(binding: FragmentProfileBinding) {
        val mLink = binding.tvLinkProfile
        mLink.movementMethod = LinkMovementMethod.getInstance()

        firebaseUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser
        refUsers = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("User").child(firebaseUser!!.uid)
        refUsers!!.addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener {
            override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {

            }

            override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
                for (p0 in snapshot.children){
                    val userName = snapshot.child("userName").value.toString()
                    val bio = snapshot.child("bio").value.toString()
                    val profileImage = snapshot.child("profile_image").value.toString()
                    val backgroundImage = snapshot.child("background_image").value.toString()
                    val link = snapshot.child("link").value.toString()

                    binding.tvProfileName.text = userName
                    binding.tvBioProfile.text = bio
                    mLink.text = link

                    context?.let { Glide.with(it.applicationContext).load(profileImage).into(binding.ivImageProfile) }
                    context?.let { Glide.with(it.applicationContext).load(backgroundImage).into(binding.ivBannerProfile) }
                }
            }
        })
    }
```

here's the textview in xml.

```
<TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvLinkProfile"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_5dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_5dp"
                android:maxWidth="@dimen/_200dp"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:text="@string/Link"
                android:textSize="@dimen/_14sp"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/ivLinkProfile"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/tvBioProfile" />
```

and here's string resource for the text

```
    <string name="Link"> <a href=""> </a></string>
```

if you know how to solve this pls share your thoughts. thank youu

Comment: So you need when the user clicks on a specific TextView, that displays a specific URL, to open the browser? Are you getting the correct URL in the TextView?

Comment: @AlexMamo yess, i already got the URL that the user input into database. it just that the textview that display the url is not clickable to open specified link browser.

Comment: What kind of object is `mLink`?

Comment: @AlexMamo it's just a variable for declaring/Initializing the textview from the layout binding. i'm not sure about what my code actually do for getting the url. that's why i need help with my code.

Comment: If `mLink` is a [TextView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView), then I really don't see any `movementMethod` inside this class.

Comment: @AlexMamo i see, i think i still have to finish the code.

Comment: @dsneykhsa please don’t add solved to the title or body of questions. The fact there is an answer with a green check mark ✅ confirms it is approved by the OP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
binding.yourTextViewId.setOnClickListener{
            val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(binding.yourTextViewId.text.toString()))
            val chooser = Intent.createChooser(intent,"Choose Your Browser")
            startActivity(chooser)
        }
```

i added the code above and set the clicklistener on the textview then it will intent to browser with current string that i already retrieve from firebase, and problem solved!

Answer (score 0):

This way you can do

```
Text1.setText(
    Html.fromHtml(
        "<a href=\"http://www.google.com\">google</a> "));
Text1.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```

Also you can try

```
SpannableString ss = new SpannableString("Android is a Software stack");
ClickableSpan clickableSpan = new ClickableSpan() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View textView) {
        startActivity(new Intent(MyActivity.this, NextActivity.class));
    }
    @Override
    public void updateDrawState(TextPaint ds) {
        super.updateDrawState(ds);
        ds.setUnderlineText(false);
    }
};
ss.setSpan(clickableSpan, 22, 27, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.hello);
textView.setText(ss);
textView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
textView.setHighlightColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
```

in xml

```
<TextView 
  ...
  android:textColorLink="@drawable/your_selector"
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Linkify concept on textview to allow its contents to become links.
Checkout this link:
[How to Linkify a TextView in Kotlin Android](https://medium.com/@rohitkumar281991/how-to-linkify-a-textview-in-kotlin-android-bbee03656571)

Comment: what exactly to do to handle the clicked link?